# I get SourceMaps.loadSourceMapContents: Could not download sourcemap from chrome-extension when debugging my Angular 4 app on Mac with VSC

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug on my MAC with Visual Studio Code.

[I have followed this instructions, but without any luck...](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2453)

They recommended to add

```
  "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
    "webpack:///./*": "${webRoot}/*"
    },
```

In the launch.json, but I still get this error...

```
SourceMaps.loadSourceMapContents: Could not download sourcemap from chrome-extension://elgalmkoelokbchhkhacckoklkejnhcd/build/content-script.js.map
SourceMaps.loadSourceMapContents: Could not download sourcemap from chrome-extension://elgalmkoelokbchhkhacckoklkejnhcd/build/ng-validate.js.map
SourceMaps.loadSourceMapContents: Could not download sourcemap from chrome-extension://elgalmkoelokbchhkhacckoklkejnhcd/build/backend.js.map
```

I have this in launch.json in Visual Studio Code

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible Node.js debug attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
 "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "nodemon",
      "runtimeExecutable": "nodemon",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "--debug=5858"
      ],
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/server/bin/www",
      "restart": true,
      "port": 5858,
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
    },
        {
          "name": "Client",
          "type": "chrome",
          "request": "launch",
          "url": "http://localhost:4200",
          "runtimeArgs": [
            "--user-data-dir",
            "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
          ],
          "sourceMaps": true,
          "trace": true,
          "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/client/",
          "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
            "webpack:///./*": "${webRoot}/*"
            },
          "userDataDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/chrome"
        },
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Server",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/server/bin/www",
      "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceRoot}/out/**/*.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```